# MapKit local search results populate the table

Tags: swift, xcode, textview, mapkit, mklocalsearch

I am trying to load the updated search results but it doesn't populate the table view.

I used this link https://www.thorntech.com/how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit/ which belongs to the previous versions but it still works very well except showing the local search results.

```
class LocationSearchTable : UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    var matchingItems:[MKMapItem] = []
    var mapView: MKMapView? = nil
    
}

extension LocationSearchTable {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let MapView = mapView,
            let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        request.region = MapView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start { response, _ in
            guard let response = response else {
                print("No response")
                return
            }
            self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

extension LocationSearchTable {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return matchingItems.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
        cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through in the debugger to identify where the problem lies?  You should also not drop the completion handler's error inout as that might tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @flanker i have stepped through in the debugger unfortunately i couldn't identify the problem. I am new to swift so i haven't understood how the completion handler works. I just followed the steps of the documentation.

Comment: My code differs from the documentation in the second extension's second method. In the documentation, method is declared as 'override func' but when I declared it as 'override func', Xcode gives me an error "Method does not override any method from its superclass" which makes sense. I don't know if it has any connection with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //use IndexPath rather than NSIndexPath and you need to use 
 //override

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath 
     indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell =tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cell")!
    let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
    cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""
    return cell
}
```

Hope it is not too late to answer you!